# Implement Fredkin gate with square root of swap

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

I would like to implement a Fredkin gate based on square root of swap and one-qubit gates. In particular, I was hoping to find the exact gate named "?" in this circuit:

[image]

In addition, I want to avoid using C-SQSWAP. Otherwise, the solution would be trivial.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This is a square root of swap circuit:

[image: sqrt swap]

You can get a CNOT operation by doing single-qubit rotations between two sqrt swaps. [Here's the circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22QFT2%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA2%22%2C1%2C%22%2B%3DA2%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22~amvp%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22SWAP%5E1%2F2%22%2C%22circuit%22%3A%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D):

[image: CNOT]

There are standard decompositions of the Fredkin gate into the Toffoli gate and CNOTs, and standard decompositions of the Toffoli gate into CNOTs and single-qubit operations. For example, here is a Fredkin decomposition used by Cirq that only uses CNOTs between adjacent qubits:

[image: Fredkin]

Replace all the CNOTs with the CNOT decomposition and [voila](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22QFT3%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA3%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%2B%3DA3%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22H%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22H%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Y%5E-%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Z%5E-%C2%BD%22%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22~amvp%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Z%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22X%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22X%5E-%C2%BD%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22~amvp%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22SWAP%5E1%2F2%22%2C%22circuit%22%3A%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%5E%C2%BD%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D):

[image: Fredkin from sqrt swap]

Of course, you would try to cancel as many of the single qubit operations as possible.

Are there better decompositions? Almost definitely. But this is one that's easy to find.

Comment: Two things. Firstly, SUPER-thanks for creating Quirk. Secondly, do you know of a decomposition of the CNOT into only SQSWAPs and Z, S & T gates ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. All those operations preserve total number of set bits, but CNOT doesn't.

Comment: Actually, they don't commute, so maybe you can escape the space.

Answer (score 2):

For other readers who, like me, would otherwise have to go and check this, the Fredkin gate is the same thing as controlled-swap.

Some insight that you can get into the construction comes by focussing only on the elements $\{|01\rangle,|10\rangle\}$ on the two target qubits. The square root of swap looks like
$$
e^{i\pi/4}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & i \\ i & 1 \end{array}\right)/\sqrt{2}
$$
on those two elements (at least, that's the definition that I'm taking). Let's all this $U$. This reminds me of the beam splitter matrix in the Mach-Zehnder interferometer, which inspired the following construction.  We have that
$$
UU=X\qquad UZUZ=\mathbb{I}.
$$
So, what we want is a sequence of V, sqrt-SWAP, V, sqrt-SWAP where V does nothing if the control qubit is in 1 (so we get the sequence $UU$), and if the control qubit is 0, does the gate $\text{diag}(1,1,-1,1)$ on the target qubits. In other words, $V$ is a controlled-controlled-phase up to a couple of bit flips.

I believe the following does the job (but of course depends on what you allow your "?" to be constructed out of):
[image]